# Extract nested fields in MyBatis annotation

Tags: java, sql, annotations, mybatis, ibatis

My program is using a `Metadata` class to describe attributes and fields of different objects:

```
class Metadata {
  private String objectType;
  private String table;
  private String idAttribute;

  private List<Attribute> attributes;
}

class Attribute {
  private String name;
  private List<Field> fields;
}

class Field {
  private String name;
  private String type;
  private int size;
}
```

Let's assume I get a JSON:

```
{
  "objectType": "OBJECT TYPE",
  "table": "objects"
  "idAttribute": "identifier";

  "attributes": [
     {
       "name": "identifier",
       "fields": [
         {
           "name": "id",
           "type": "NUMERIC",
           "size": 32
         },
         {
           "name": "version"
           "type": "NUMERIC",
           "size": 8
         }
       ]
     },
     // many other attributes
   ]
 }
```

`fields` are representing actual columns in a `table` from my DB. I want to check the `version` of an object of specified `objectType` and given `id` using MyBatis mapper:

```
@Select(
  "SELECT ${metadata.attributes.${metadata.idAttribute}.fields.(get the field name 'version' somehow) " + 
  "FROM ${metadata.table} " +
  "WHERE ${metadata.attributes.${metadata.idAttribute}.fields.(get the field name 'id' somehow)} 
  = #{id} "
)
public byte getVersion(@Param("metadata") Metadata metadata),
                       @Param("id") long id);
```

As you see, the query above looks creepy anf I don't know **how to extract concrete fields by dynamic values**.

Is it possible at all to do this in MyBatis, or there is no other way, than to get all nested fields in java and then pass them to the `Mapper`?